# How to Override Css property of any Jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins, groovy, plugins

For example Jenkins'Active choice parameter plugin" provides drop down option as part of plugin functinality. Now in my use case I want to resize the width of drop down to slandered size, so how can we override the plugin css property ?? Alternate idea to achive this is usecase also welcomed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have [Custom Theme plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Simple+Theme+Plugin) installed, you can override css settings in Jenkins via:
`Manage Jenkins > Configure system > Theme > Extra CSS`.

Add for example some stylin on the select box (like example below), click Apply & Save and you override some settings.

```
select {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: red;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Or f.e. if you don't want the pipeline console output the pipeline lines to be there:

**Console output before**

```
Running on xxxxx in xxxxxx
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] properties
[Pipeline] stage
```

Add extra CSS (depending on the class name and your choice):

```
.pipeline-annotated {
   visibility: hidden;
}

.pipeline-new-node {
    display; none;
}
```

**Console output after**

```
Running on xxxxx in xxxxxx
Wiping out workspace first.
Cloning the remote Git repository
```